# Partition an array into two subarrays, each having maximum sum and equal to other array sum

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming, subset-sum

Given an array of integers, how can we divide it into two subsets such that the sum of elements in one array is equal to the sum of elements in the other, and that this sum is maximum? We are free to not select a number from the given array.

```
eg.
Given array: [2, 3, 4, 1, 6] 
Possible subsets with equal sum:
 a. [2, 3] and [4, 1] where sum = 5
 b. [2, 6] and [3, 4, 1] where sum = 8
 c. [2, 3, 1] and [6] where sum = 6 and we didn't include 4 in subsets

Here b is the expected subset.
```

Also, 1 <= arr[i] <=1000

max length of array is 1000

Comment: how big is the array? How big are the  numbers inside it?

Comment: is it an example of max heap??

Comment: how is [2, 6] and [3, 4, 1] 2 subarrays? seems like 2 subsets

Comment: I'm wondering whether it's from any ongoing competition. The exact same question was already asked few days ago.

Comment: This question is somewhat on the lines of subset sum problem. Suppose given array A has n elements. Let's say Sum is the total sum of the elements of the array. Now let's divide the Sum, so each subarray needs to have the elements which sum to Sum/2. So now you can run the algorithm for solving subset sum https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-subset-sum-problem/ with Sum/2.